# While comparing the equations in the align* environment using the & sign before the = sign, it is giving error "! Misplaced alignment tab character &"

Tags: equations, errors, align, positioning, compilation-error

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {geometry}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\begin {document}
With align* command :-\\
\\
\\
\begin {align*}
a = b + c
\\ abcd = f + g + h
\end {align*}\\
\\
\\
\\
Without align* command :-\\
\\
\\
a = b +c
\\abcd = f + g + h
\\
\\
\\
With align* command and ''and'' symbol used:-\\
\\
\\
\begin {align*}
a & = b + c
\\ abcd & = f + g + h
\end {align*}\\
\\
\\
\\
Without align* command and `'and'' symbol used :-\\
\\
\\
a &= b +c
\\abcd &= f + g + h
\\
\\
\\
\end {document}
```

Comment: the error is in the last case where you have used `&` outside of an alignment, simply remove it. also remove all the `\\ ` which generate `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 11--26
`

Comment: every `\\ ` in this example is wrong except for `\\ abcd & = f + g + h` and even they are placed in an unusual positiion `\\ ` ends the line, so it would be more usual to place the `\\ ` at the end of the line above  after `+ c`